# R - Import then export multiband RGB aerial image .tif

Tags: r, rgb, raster

I want to import an aerial image in .tif format, and then export in the same colour format. I imagine this is a simple task but I can't find a way to do it. The original files are coloured when viewed in Windows Photo Viewer and Google Earth, but the exports are black and white.

Ultimately, I want to crop/merge multiple images to create a single aerial image map from approx 6 tiles. Of the 6 tiles, I am only interested in about 30% of the area (the bits over the water, plus a ~20 m buffer), so the idea is to cut down on image size by keeping the parts I want as a single file, rather than importing all 6 tiles. I can open one .tif in Google Earth as a coloured aerial image, which is what I want for my custom-boundary map/image.

At the moment, I am struggling to import then export a single .tif in the same Google Earth-readable coloured image format. I'm importing the files into R using `raster`, and have tried exporting using `writeRaster`, but the images are black and white when viewed in GE. I believe this might mean the image is rendering only a single (RGB) layer of the image? However, `plotRGB()` in R is able to plot it in colour.

You can download the file I'm working with from [my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OKFb9LB4iZzdhemVQtxPN3yOOsBGMucB/view), or search for it on [Elvis](https://elevation.fsdf.org.au/) (satellite image data from inside the Australian Capital Territory, Australia, approx -35.467437, 148.824043). Thanks for any help or direction to some instructions.

This is where I'm at so far...

```
# import and plot the tif - plots nicely in colour
brick('ACT2017-RGB-10cm_6656073_55_0001_0001.tif') %>% 
  plotRGB
```

This is what I see from `plotRGB()`, and also when I open the original in Google Earth (this is the desired output colour).
[image]

```
# export
brick('ACT2017-RGB-10cm_6656073_55_0001_0001.tif') %>% 
  writeRaster('my_output.tif')

# then import the export
brick('my_output.tif') %>% 
  plotRGB
```

`my_export.tif` plots in colour in R, but black and white in Google Earth.

Comment: do you specifically need to do this in R?  have you tried QGIS?  It will be able to do it

Comment: It doesn't _have to be_ R, but I don't use QGIS so was hoping for an R example. If I can't work it out I'll have a look at QGIS. Thanks

Comment: Usually we use GDAL tools/libraries to do multiband manipulation (and in general to handle geoTIFF files. Probably there is also a R package which provide GDAL data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with `terra` (the replacement for `raster`). For this example to work well, you need version 1.4-1 or higher; currently the development version, that you can install with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

```
library(terra)
f <- 'ACT2017-RGB-10cm_6656073_55_0001_0001.tif'
r <- rast(f)
plot(r)
```

Since this is a "RGB" image, there is no need to call plotRGB explicitly

I create two sub-images for this example

```
ex <- ext(665000, 665500, 6073000, 6073500)
x <- crop(r, ex)
ey <- ext(665500, 666000, 6073500, 6074000)
y <- crop(r, ey)
```

They still look good with

```
plot(x)
plot(y)
```

Now merge them

```
m <- merge(x, y)
```

After merge, the RGB, channels are lost and need to be redeclared

```
RGB(m) <- 1:3
```

And you can write to disk

```
z <- writeRaster(m, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
plot(z)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps Robert, but `plot(z)` produces an error: `Error in grDevices::rgb(RGB[, 1], RGB[, 2], RGB[, 3], alpha = alpha, maxColorValue = scale) : color intensity NA, not in 0:255`. However, `test.tif` does open in Windows Photo Viewer and Google Earth as desired. So, technically this answers my question but it would be nice if `plot(z)` worked. I have updated to the latest version of R and `terra 1.3.22`, but it still produces the error.

Comment: I also get 2 errors the first time I execute `plot(r)` per session: `Error in x$.self$finalize() : attempt to apply non-function` and `Error in (function (x)  : attempt to apply non-function` (2 times each, total 4 errors). And again, I get the first error 2 times after the first execution of `merge(x, y)` per session.

Comment: The max values in `z` are `254` for each layer, so I tried `plotRGB(z, scale = 254)` but still got the same error.

Comment: I am sorry, I am using the development version (install with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')` in which this bug (RGB plotting with NAs; your first comment) is fixed. 2nd comment is a nuisance that can be ignored.

Comment: Ah ok awesome, I'll try the dev version. Thanks for the help Robert!